# How to call corresponding Html based on Json data value Description as filename with extensions and Path as Path?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

Here Am created Some sample file. its working fine now... if I give direct Html element in Description (i.e) "Description": "Third"... But what exactly need is I will put that Html Element separate file And in Description only that external file name only if you want In Addition col as Path you can add...
is it any possible way is there to call corresponding Html file with name and path?

```js
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);


app.directive('sample', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            array: '='
        },
        template: '<ul ng-repeat="arr in array" title={{arr.title}} ng-bind-html="arr.Description | to_trusted"></ul>',

        link: function (scope) {

        }

    };
})

app.filter('to_trusted', ['$sce', function($sce){
    return function(text) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
    };
}]);

  app.controller('SampleCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    
              $scope.array = [{
                       "title": "0",
                       "Description": "<h1>Here I will give Html file Name only (i.e) FirstPage.html while loading time i need to call that Html file</h1>",
                        "Path":"HerePathofthefile"
                  
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "1",
                        "Description": "<h2>If I give Html element here its working is it any possible way is there to call corresponding Html file</h2>"
                      ,
                        "Path":"HerePathofthefile"
                      
                    },
                    {
                        "title": 2,
                        "Description": "<h3>Second</h3>"
                      ,
                        "Path":"HerePathofthefile"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": 3,
                        "Description": "<h4>Third</h4>"
                      ,
                        "Path":"HerePathofthefile"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": 4,
                        "Description": "<h5>Fourth</h5>"
                      ,
                        "Path":"HerePathofthefile"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": 5,
                        "Description": "<h6>Fifth</h6>"
                      ,
                        "Path":"HerePathofthefile"
                    }];
         
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="SampleCtrl">
 <sample array=array></sample>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ng-include to render html file on your page or can use it in tabs and pass it as content ,for a tab based ng-include example please have look to this fiddle.

```
        <tabset> 
        <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabsMenu"  active="tab.active"> 
        <tab-heading> {{tab.title}} 
        <i ng-if =tab.closableTab class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove closeTabIcon" ng-click="removeTab($index)"></i> 
        </tab-heading> 
        <ng-include src="tab.url"></ng-include> 
        </tab>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pawanFiddle/mwqty2sf/5/